Can't fix "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools.extern.six'"
I've been trying to test out a colony counter code I found on GitHub that could be of use. However, the windows that generates when i run the code aren't the same as the ones that are demonstrated in their GitHub page, so I figured that I probably have to install the requirements.txt for it to work as intended. For clarification, this is what the window should look like. On my end, the window looks like this instead.
So as I tried to install the requirements to see if  it works, it gives me this error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools.extern.six'
As a reminder, I'm running the code with VS Code and default language Python 3.11. I'm not sure if I'm missing something or is because the code was worked with Python 3.8. The code remains intact when i downloaded it. I haven't made a single change to it. Here are some of the recomended prequesites:

numpy 1.20.1

OpenCV 4.5.1.48

screeninfo 0.8.1 (and its associated requirements)



I received the same error and I had to update my version of Numpy. I was also using 1.20.1, but I updated it to version 2.0.0 and no longer get the error.
You can either do a pip install numpy==2.0.0 or you can update it in your requirements.txt directly with this:
numpy==2.0.0

Once you have updated the requirements.txt, you can run pip install -r requirements.txt again. If it's like the project I'm working on, you'll probably get another error caused by another package that needs updating.
I hope that helps!
